# Have Bullseye and Hawkeye ever faced off?

Tags: marvel, hawkeye

In the Marvel universe, the two greatest marksmen are Hawkeye (either Clint Barton or Kate Bishop) and Bullseye. Considering both have been around for over forty years, have they ever faced off in the comics or in other media? If so, who was the victor?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hawkeye and Bullseye faced off in [Hawkeye: Freefall #6](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/82635/hawkeye_freefall_2020_6).

[image: The two face off, bows drawn at each other. Hawkeye: "Drop it, Bullseye". Bullseye: "You feeling okay?"]

They seem pretty evenly matched and after [breaking several arrows on each other's arrows](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShootTheBullet), Hawkeye used a trick (exploding) arrow and Bullseye was defeated.

[image: Hawkeye: "Not sure your aim is better than mine, Bullseye. But you know what beats aim evert time?" Bullseye: "Speed?" Hawkeye: "No. Trick arrows, you dumb $&%#." Explosions]

---

They also fought in the Earth-807128 (Old Man Logan) universe in [Old Man Hawkeye #9](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/69223/old_man_hawkeye_2018_9), but it wasn't much of a fair fight. Clint is going blind, versus Bullseye who's had cyber enhancement. Hawkeye is easily defeated by a thrown weapon.

[image: Both are elderly, Hawkeye says "Owwwww!" and collapses from Bullseye's thrown knife]

Comment: Confusing that Hawkeye is wearing Bullseye's costume in the first set of panels.

Comment: @jamesdlin - Aye, I did consider adding in some of the back-story, then decided against it because he's identified him by name. I came to the conclusion that anyone interested in finding out more can always click the linkie.